# How to insert text outside a plot

Tags: text, matplotlib

I have the following plot (with 3 rows and 4 columns):

```
f, ((ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4), (ax5, ax6, ax7, ax8), (ax9, ax10, ax11, ax12)) = plt.subplots(3,   4, sharex = 'col', sharey = 'row')
ax1.set_title('column1')
ax1.plot([x], [y])
ax5.plot([x1],[y1])
ax9.plot([x2],[y2])
ax2.set_title('column2')
ax2.plot([x3],[x4])
ax6.plot([x5],[x6])
.....
```

How is it possible to insert text outside the plot window? For each row I would like to write a sentence on the right end side of the plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`ax.set_title()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_title) function.

Alternatively, you might want to place your text using the [`ax.text()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.text) function. Note that you can use values in the position argument that go beyond your axes ranges. Additionally, you can set the reference coordinate system using the `transform` parameter.

Comment: There as also `annotate` which is more flexible than `text`

Comment: The ax.text() link is now broken I'm afraid. Also I am not sure what you mean by "you can use values...that extend". If I place ax.text() outside the subplot, it is not displayed.